# Mostrar solo días especificos mediante una funcion

Tags: php

Tengo un metodo que me muestra todos los dias Lunes en un rango dado de fechas. Es el Siguiente:

```
<?php
$fechaInicio=strtotime("2019-08-01");
$fechaFin=strtotime("2019-11-20");
//Recorro las fechas y con la función strotime obtengo los lunes
for($i=$fechaInicio; $i<=$fechaFin; $i+=86400){
    //Sacar el dia de la semana con el modificador N de la funcion date
    $dia = date('N', $i);
    if($dia==1){
        echo "Lunes. ". date ("d-m-Y", $i)."<br>";
    }
}
```

Como podran ver si cambio el valor de la variable $dia y por ejemplo le pongo 3 me devolvera en el echo todos los miercoles que existan en ese rango de fechas. Pues bien. Lo que necesito es convertirla a funcion con 3 parametros $diaini, $diafin y el dia o los dias solo que quiero que muestre mediante $solodiaX

y lo he hecho asi:

```
function solodiaindicado($fechaini, $fechafin, $solodiaX)
{
   $fechaini = strtotime($fechaini);
   $fechafin = strtotime($fechafin);

   for($i=$fechaini; $i<=$fechafin; $i+=86400){
        $solodiaX = date('N', $i);

switch ($solodiaX) {
      case 1:
        echo "Lunes. ". date ("d-m-Y", $i)."<br>";
        break;
      case 2:
         echo "Martes. ". date ("d-m-Y",$i)."<br>";
          break;
      case 3:
          echo "Miercoles. ". date ("d-m-Y",$i)."<br>";    
        break;
      case 4:
          echo "Jueves. ". date ("d-m-Y",$i)."<br>";
         break;
      case 5:   
            echo "Viernes. ". date ("d-m-Y",$i)."<br>";
        break;

       default:
        echo "DIA NO HABIL. "."<br>";

    }
```

y la llamo asi:

```
require_once "funciones.php";
print_r(solodiaindicado('2019-06-19','2019-06-30', 3));
```

pero me muestra todos los dias y no solo los miercoles. Ya he probado con el Elseif con el Else if pero me sigue mostrando todos los dias dentro de ese rango
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente: (Refactorice un poco el codigo para evitar el switch y el Lunes, Martes, ... continuamente)

```
solodiaindicado("2019-08-01", "2019-11-20", 1);

function solodiaindicado($fechaini, $fechafin, $solodiaX)
{
    //Con esto garantizas que el dia pasado por parametro sea el correcto
    if($solodiaX < 1 && $solodiaX > 7) {
        echo "Dia incorrecto";
        return;
    }

    $fechaInicio=strtotime($fechaini);
    $fechaFin=strtotime($fechafin);

    //Creas un arreglo con los valores de los nombres de los dias
    $dias = [1 => "Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sabado", "Domingo"];
    //Recorro las fechas y con la función strotime obtengo los lunes
    for($i=$fechaInicio; $i<=$fechaFin; $i+=86400){
        //Sacar el dia de la semana con el modificador N de la funcion date
        $dia = date('N', $i); 
        //Si coincide el dia con el que queremos mostrar....       
        if($dia == $solodiaX){
            echo $dias[$solodiaX]." ".date ("d-m-Y", $i)."<br>";
        }
    }    
}
```

**EDITADO:**
Si deseas poder obtener por mas de un dia, ejemplo los Lunes y los martes puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
solodiaindicado("2019-08-01", "2019-11-20", [1, 2]);

function solodiaindicado($fechaini, $fechafin, $solodiaX)
{
    $solodiaX = is_array($solodiaX) ? $solodiaX : [$solodiaX];

    foreach($solodiaX as $sdia) {
        //Con esto garantizas que el dia pasado por parametro sea el correcto
        if($sdia < 1 && $sdia > 7) {
            echo "Dia incorrecto";
            return;
        }
    }


    $fechaInicio=strtotime($fechaini);
    $fechaFin=strtotime($fechafin);

    //Creas un arreglo con los valores de los nombres de los dias
    $dias = [1 => "Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sabado", "Domingo"];
    //Recorro las fechas y con la función strotime obtengo los lunes
    for($i=$fechaInicio; $i<=$fechaFin; $i+=86400){
        //Sacar el dia de la semana con el modificador N de la funcion date
        $dia = date('N', $i); 
        //Si coincide el dia con el que queremos mostrar....       
        if(in_array($dia, $solodiaX)){
            echo $dias[$dia]. date ("d-m-Y", $i)."<br>";
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Daniel Ramos Diaz de Villegas Un Genio Funciona Excelente! Disculpame si consulto algo mas, para que acepte mas de 1 dia por ej. Martes y Jueves le he agregado al parametro solodiaX array() pero este cambio que hice no me funciona podrias decirme como lo soluciono? Desde ya muchas Daniel

Comment: Edite la respuesta con otra opcion para lo ke kerias

Comment: Excelente Daniel!! Me faltan palabras para agradecerte la verdad un Genio!

Comment: Jaajaja nada de genialidad Juan me alegro ke te haya servido